# Compile web application project ascx into dll

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Is it possible to compile a web application project .ascx (user control) into a dll?

I want to do the following:

1. Use the same control in multiple websites
2. Embed css and .js as resources into the control
3. Be able to update super easy. If the user control updates, I just want to update 1 .dll

I have successfully followed this article, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx.

However, that uses web site projects, and I cannot embed js css as resources into web site projects.

Any ideas? Am I going about this wrong, should I change the approach?

Comment: Have you analized the solution I pasted? It works very well for creating a user control library. I would avoid the creation of user control library if possible as other say, but if you have no option take a look to the article

Answer (score 6):

Conversion is easy, and could even be fully automated.  It simply requires changing a few settings and base classes in the DLL Project you want your ASCX controls embedded in.

**1...** For each UserControl, set the ASCX file's Build Action (under Properties) to "Embedded Resource", and delete its associated designer file.

**2...** Save the project.

**3...** Right click the project and choose "Unload Project".

**4...** Right click it again and choose the "Edit *.csproj" option.

Change sections that look like this (where the asterisk represents your class name):

```
<Compile Include="*.ascx.cs">
    <DependentUpon>*.ascx</DependentUpon>
    <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
```

to look like this

```
<Compile Include="*.ascx.cs" />
```

That will cause the code-behind files to be compiled independently of the ASCX files.

**5...** Save changes, and right click the project and choose "Reload Project".

**6...** Open all your "*.ascx.cs" files and make them inherit from the following custom UserControl class, instead of the System.Web.UI.UserControl class (you may need to locate parent classes to complete this step).

```
public class UserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected override void FrameworkInitialize()
    {
        base.FrameworkInitialize();
        string content = String.Empty;
        Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream( GetType().FullName + ".ascx" );
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Control userControl = Page.ParseControl( content );
        this.Controls.Add( userControl );
    }
}
```

This base class will take care of loading and parsing the embedded ASCX file.

**7...** Finally, you may need to place ASCX files in subfolders so that their resource names (automatically determined by folder path) match the full type name of their associated class (plus ".ascx").  Assuming your root namespace matches your project name, then a class named "ProjectName.Namespace1.Namespace2.ClassName" will need its ASCX file in a subfolder "Namespace1\Namespace2", so it gets embedded with the name "ProjectName.Namespace1.Namespace2.ClassName.ascx".

And that's it!  Once you compile the DLL and include it in another project, you can instantiate instances of your user controls using the "new" operator, like any other class.  As always, your control will be "caught up" to the current page event once added as a child control to the page or another control on the page.

Comment: I've tried to use this approach when creating really complex control, but didn't work. Apparently the problem is in ParseControl method, which cannot handle data binding expressions like Eval and Bind. Any idea with this?

Comment: This is pretty amazing. I've managed to get it to work with a few tweaks. Step 7 was not required, it did not like having sub-dirs for each namespace, but worked when in the root. Each front end control had to be manually declared/registered via this.FindControl('litOutput'); and events had to be registered within the back end. Apart from that I've had no other problems so far!

Comment: I had an exception within the ParseControl Method. It tried to parse the 'Inherits="Namespace.Class"' part of the ascx file and couldn't find the mentioned type. So I removed the Inherits part from my ascx file and it worked.

Comment: Once I compile and consume the dll in WebApp, I get the error which states:  "Could not load type WebApp.UserControls.MyControl" and it's referring to this line in the ascx file: `<%@ Control Language="vb" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="WebApp.UserControls.MyControl" %>`. Here is my solution structure: WebApp.sln > WebApp, WebApp.UserControls. The "WebApp.UserControls" project has the following files: MyControl.ascx and MyControl.ascx.vb -- **Can you clairify the directory structure and the `<%@ Control... %> tag and how they relate to the system as a whole?**

Answer (score 3):

It is difcult to use user controls in this way due to the markup ascx file.  If you want to create reusable control libraries your are much better off creating custom controls.

Comment: I'd add to that, if the user control isn't highly composite, then this is the least painful way to go.  In fact I've refactored code so that my ascx files weren't composite controls just so they'd be easier to make into server controls, often these inherit from some built in ASP.NET control.

Comment: Creating a custom control isn't really an option in this case, I am getting the code from a third party, which I am trying to then embed into 3 different websites. I don't have control over how I get the code, and I don't want to re-write it into a custom control, especially as every update they give will have to be re-written.

Comment: Rather than trying to crowbar user controlls into a dll you can reference, you would be better off just using the source of the user controls in each web app and keeping them in sync using source control such as subversion's externals feature. http://justaddwater.dk/2007/10/23/setting-up-subversion-externals-with-tortoisesvn/

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to convert user control to the custom control. There is an nice article on [MSDN: Turning an .ascx User Control into a Redistributable Custom Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx) which describes exactly how to do that. Here is the summary:

> 1. Write your user control as you normally would, typically using the Visual Studio designer.
> 2. Test it using a simple page before trying to deploy it.
> 3. Deploy the application to precompile it.
> 4. Grab the user control's assembly produced by the deployment step,
>      and you're essentially done: You have your custom control.
> 5. Finally, use your custom control in other apps the same way as you
>      always use custom controls.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it once and I followed this article

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/EmbeddedUserControl.aspx

It's based on the possibility of mounting a virtual file system on different places (an assembly, database, etc)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few articles out there on how to do exactly that:

http://www.nathanblevins.com/Articles/Compile-a-Web-User-Control-into-a-DLL-.Net-c-.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2005/10/30/487160.aspx

Comment: Both of those links deal with Web Site Projects, you cannot embed resources into a web site project as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but yes its possible.. I do it all the time, see https://kocubinski.wordpress.com/2013/05/06/compile-asp-net-webforms-ascx-usercontrols-into-assembly-for-re-use/