# ASP.NET - How do I package a Web User Control (.ascx) in a DLL for use in other applications?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have developed a paging control that I would like to use in a variety of applications, both C# and VB.NET.

I'd like to package the entire thing, markup and all, into a DLL which I can add as a reference from my other applications' bin folders.

If this is not possible, or is a very bad idea, what is the recommended method for deploying a web user control amongst multiple applications?

(I like how easy it is to utilize Ajax Toolkit controls from a single DLL, although I'm not sure if those are custom controls or web user controls)

Thanks

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806268/compile-web-application-project-ascx-into-dll

Comment: In fact, it's a duplicate. The answer is, "make it a custom control", as user controls are meant to be quick, and easy, and not reused like that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My initial search didn't locate that. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you still interested I paste a link to a codeproject article where you have a interesting option for creating a user control library. I implemented it for a project a worked very well.

Here is the link

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/EmbeddedUserControl.aspx