# Accessing user controls from a separate application but within same application pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls

I'm attempting to create a form page that involves the use of some user controls, and the `Item.aspx` file contains this line:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/project/path/X.ascx" TagName="X" TagPrefix="uc" %>
```

but somehow I keep getting the following warnings when I try to build my application:

```
Element 'X' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.
File '~/project/path/X.ascx' was not found.
```

The user controls are contained in a different application, but within the same application pool on the local host. I'm completely new to C#/.Net/web development, but from what I've been able to gather, it seems that I can only access user controls and specify paths from the application root however, so the only solution I've been able to successfully implement is to copy the entire `project` folder into the application directory.

I'm working entirely in C#, no VB.

The codebase is established however; and it's already working without this, to the best of my knowledge, so this seems like a clunky hack. Then did I configure something incorrectly? Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: User controls can't be used that way. They have to be in the same application. In fact, it used to be the case that they had to be in the same project. I was not aware that had changed. User controls are meant to be a simplified way of creating custom controls. If you need more capabilities than they have, then you need to move to Custom Controls.

Comment: I'm not sure about them having to be in the same project, but I'm pretty sure it has to be the same application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to create a DLL file out of your control(s) and then reuse it in both of your projects. There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806268/compile-web-application-project-ascx-into-dll) about that on stackoverlow